# Problem while running Resque -Sceduler in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error while running resque scheduler on capistrano server in production mode. I'd appreciate any help,its urgent for me.

(in /data/amsapp_staging/releases/20101008121309)
** Invoke resque:scheduler (first_time)
** Invoke resque:scheduler_setup (first_time)
** Execute resque:scheduler_setup
** Invoke resque:setup (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute resque:setup
** Execute resque:scheduler
2010-10-08 07:44:46 Scheduling create_ams_jobs 
2010-10-08 07:44:46 Scheduling create_ams_daily_mailer 
rake aborted!
time's up!
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/SystemTimer-1.2/lib/system_timer/concurrent_timer_pool.rb:63:in `trigger_next_expired_timer_at'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/SystemTimer-1.2/lib/system_timer/concurrent_timer_pool.rb:68:in`trigger_next_expired_timer'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/SystemTimer-1.2/lib/system_timer.rb:81:in `install_ruby_sigalrm_handler'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in`synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/SystemTimer-1.2/lib/system_timer.rb:79:in `install_ruby_sigalrm_handler'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redis-2.0.10/lib/redis/client.rb:215:in`call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redis-2.0.10/lib/redis/client.rb:215:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redis-2.0.10/lib/redis/client.rb:215:in`new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redis-2.0.10/lib/redis/client.rb:215:in `connect_to'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/SystemTimer-1.2/lib/system_timer.rb:56:in`timeout_after'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redis-2.0.10/lib/redis/client.rb:276:in `with_timeout'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redis-2.0.10/lib/redis/client.rb:214:in`connect_to'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redis-2.0.10/lib/redis/client.rb:23:in `connect'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redis-2.0.10/lib/redis/client.rb:242:in`ensure_connected'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redis-2.0.10/lib/redis/client.rb:268:in `ensure_connected'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in`synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redis-2.0.10/lib/redis/client.rb:264:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redis-2.0.10/lib/redis/client.rb:268:in`ensure_connected'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redis-2.0.10/lib/redis/client.rb:61:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redis-2.0.10/lib/redis/client.rb:199:in`logging'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redis-2.0.10/lib/redis/client.rb:60:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redis-2.0.10/lib/redis/client.rb:34:in`call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redis-2.0.10/lib/redis.rb:308:in `zrangebyscore'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redis-namespace-0.8.0/lib/redis/namespace.rb:188:in`send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/redis-namespace-0.8.0/lib/redis/namespace.rb:188:in `method_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/resque-scheduler-1.9.6/lib/resque_scheduler.rb:93:in`next_delayed_timestamp'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/resque-scheduler-1.9.6/lib/resque/scheduler.rb:85:in `handle_delayed_items'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/resque-scheduler-1.9.6/lib/resque/scheduler.rb:29:in`run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/resque-scheduler-1.9.6/lib/resque/scheduler.rb:28:in `loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/resque-scheduler-1.9.6/lib/resque/scheduler.rb:28:in`run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/resque-scheduler-1.9.6/lib/resque_scheduler/tasks.rb:13
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in`execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in`execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in`synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in`invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in`top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in`top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in`top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in`standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in`load'
/usr/bin/rake:19

Answer (score 0):

To figure it out we need to Pass the RAILS_ENV variable value e.g. production,staging,development.Depends on your need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the RAILS_ENV or RACK_ENV variable when you're running the rake task. At the top of your Rakefile, you can put the following and check

`require 'resque/tasks'

ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'production'

require 'myapp'`